# The two regular expressions abc and abc(φ)* are equivalent. (T/F)

Tags: equivalence-relations, regular-expressions

I keep going back and forth on this question. Obviously both expressions will always begin with "abc" but I am not sure what effect the addition of Phi will have on the expression. It is an empty set, yet "abc" does not contain the empty set so they would not be equivalent?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your phrase "empty set" could be a language, but cannot be a substring of a regular expression.  The phrase "empty string" describes something that cannot be a language, but that can be a substring of a regular expression.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: @EricTowers We have been using phi to represent the empty *set* in my class and e to represent the empty *string*. So this question is asking if the addition of the kleene star of an empty string is equivalent to the former string.

Comment: In your comment: "$\varnothing$ is the empty set" is the former, "$e$ is the empty string" is the latter.  Then you refer to the former as a string.  I iterate my position that you are not precisely distinguishing strings and sets.

Answer (score 0):

If in your notation $\varphi$ denotes the empty string, they are equivalent. If $\varphi$ is anything else, they are not.

Comment: We have been using φ to represent the empty *set* and e to represent the empty *string*. So you're saying if it represents the empty set then it is not? That sounds right to me.

Comment: @pberganator I don't think Kleene star operates on *sets* so $\varphi$ cannot possibly mean the empty set in this instance. The Kleene star only operates on *strings*